# Equation of line from loglog plot

Tags: plotting, fitting

Given some data that looks linear on a ListLogLogPlot, how can I find the correct equation (and particularly, the correct slope of the line)? I have a sample code here

```
data = {{1012*10^23, 0.64/10}, {669.83*10^23, 
   0.866647113123/10}, {405*10^23, 1.30/10}, {88.6*10^23, 
   4.32/10}, {30.4*10^23, 10.5/10}, {13.4*10^23, 
   20.22/10}, {5.97*10^23, 38.42/10}, {3.26*10^23, 61.94/10}}

H = LinearModelFit[Log10@data, x, x]
```

This yields

> ```
> 19.6255 - 0.800901 x
> ```

But when I try

```
G = ListLogLogPlot[data]
Show[G]
```

How can I also see the best fit line along with it? `Show[G,H]` and similar attempts didn't work. Also, is the slope of the best fit line `-0.8`? That is, is my relationship `y = x^(-0.8)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Show[{
  ListPlot[Log10@data],
  Plot[Normal[H], {x, 23, 26}]
  }]
```

[image]

Have fun!